# Firebase Functions - Stripe production mode not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe in an app with Firebase Functions.

I store the Stripe keys in the Firebase environment via the following:

```
firebase functions:config:set
```

All works in Test mode.

Now I would like to enable Stripe in Production mode.

I replaced my Stripe keys to use the Production "live" keys.

I verified the new variables are set using the following:

```
firebase functions:config:get
```

I see that the "public_key" and "secret_key" values have the Production values, "pk_live....." and "sk_live.....", respectively.

I deployed the Firebase functions again, after setting the new environment values.

But, when using Stripe in my app, it still shows "Test Mode".

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Below is a screenshot of the Stripe dialog where it indicates "Test mode".

[image]

I reviewed the cloud functions in Google Cloud and they have the correct keys:

[image]

Comment: Where are you seeing test mode indicated? Are you sure the live keys are being used? There might be another deployment step required for Firebase. Another option would be configuring both live & test keys and then having a separate variable operate as a switch between them. eg: `if (USE_LIVE) then {sk=SK_LIVE} else {sk=SK_TEST}` etc.

Comment: This sounds like primarily an issue with your firebase environment variables, though.

Comment: I edited the post and provided a screenshot of the Stripe dialog.  I will double check the environment variables again

Comment: I edited the post and provided a screenshot of the cloud function in Google Cloud, which shows that the keys in the environment variables are the correct values.